# C# dynamic + System.Reflection.Emit = do not mix?

Tags: c#, reflection, dynamic, reflection.emit

Why does the code like this:

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Reflection.Emit;

class Program
{
  static Type CreateDynamicType()
  {
    var typeBuilder = AppDomain.CurrentDomain
      .DefineDynamicAssembly(
        name: new AssemblyName("FooAssembly"),
        access: AssemblyBuilderAccess.Run)
      .DefineDynamicModule("FooModule")
      .DefineType("Foo", TypeAttributes.Class);

    typeBuilder
      .DefineDefaultConstructor(MethodAttributes.Public);

    var method = typeBuilder
      .DefineMethod("SayHello", MethodAttributes.Public);

    var il = method.GetILGenerator();
    il.EmitWriteLine("Hello!");
    il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

    return typeBuilder.CreateType();
  }

  static void Main()
  {
    var type = CreateDynamicType();
    dynamic instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
    instance.SayHello();
  }
}
```

Produces the exception:

> Unhandled Exception:
>   Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: 'object' does
>   not contain a definition for 'SayHello'

But calls via reflection API perfectly works. Any ideas?

Answer (score 9):

`dynamic` won't resolve members on internal types from different assemblies.
(just like the compiler won't)

Make the type public.